# Understanding SVM mathematics

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, linear-algebra

I was referring [SVM section](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes3.pdf) of Andrew Ng's course notes for Stanford CS229 Machine Learning course. On pages 14 and 15, he says:

> Consider the picture below:
> [image]
>
> How can we find the value of $\gamma^{(i)}$? Well, $w/\Vert w\Vert$ is a unit-length vector
> pointing in the same direction as $w$. Since, point $A$ represents $x^{(i)}$, we therefore find that the point $B$ is given by $x^{(i)} − \gamma^{(i)}·w/\Vert w\Vert$. But this point lies on the decision boundary, and all points $x$ on the decision boundary satisfy the equation $w^Tx + b = 0$. Hence, $$w^T\left(x^{(i)}-\gamma^{(i)}\frac{w}{\Vert w \Vert}\right)+b=0$$
> Solving for $\gamma^{(i)}$ yields $$\color{red}{\gamma^{(i)}=\frac{w^Tx^{(i)}+b}{\Vert w\Vert}}$$

I am not getting how the last red-colored equality is arrived. I am getting something like this:
$$w^T\left(x^{(i)}-\gamma^{(i)}\frac{w}{\Vert w \Vert}\right)+b=0$$
$$\rightarrow w^Tx^{(i)}-\gamma^{(i)}\frac{w^Tw}{\Vert w \Vert}+b=0$$
$$\rightarrow w^Tx^{(i)}+b=\gamma^{(i)}\frac{w^Tw}{\Vert w \Vert}$$

How can I proceed further to equality in red color? Do I have to divide both the sides again by $\Vert w \Vert$ to get the following?
$$\rightarrow \frac{w^Tx^{(i)}+b}{\Vert w \Vert}=\gamma^{(i)}\frac{w^Tw}{\Vert w \Vert\Vert w \Vert}$$

But then how $\frac{w^Tw}{\Vert w \Vert\Vert w \Vert}$ equals to $1$?

Comment: That's a pretty standard fact; see (what is currently) the fourth displayed equation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition

Comment: Yeah... I myself jotted down [little proof](https://i.postimg.cc/SsZLpj69/image.png) long back, but forgot it for a while. Now wondering if $\Vert w\Vert$ is pure magnitude, then how it involves direction component of $w$ and $w^T$ and thus how dividing $w^Tw$ (which involves both direction and magnitude) with $\Vert w\Vert\Vert w\Vert$ (which is pure magnitude) yields $1$ (which is pure magnitude). Am I thinking non-sense?

Comment: As you see in your linked proof, after the transpose-and-multiply, the result of $w^T w$ is a scalar, not a vector anymore.

Comment: Aahhh, thats again a basic fact: "vector dot product is always scalar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $w^Tw = \Vert w \Vert^2$ this stems directly from the definitions of norm and matrix product (assuming $w$ is column vector as usually taken) and one can expand the two sides to prove it easily.

**Note** that technically $w^Tw$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix but any such matrix is *identified* with its single scalar entry. So it is simply a scalar number. Or equivalently any scalar value is also a $1 \times 1$ matrix.